# how to design a tree with css without using (:before, :last-child and Jquery)

Tags: css

How can I design a tree without using (`:before`, `:last-child` and `:after`) because they are not supported in my project (I am using IE7). The problem is that the left border of the list does not stop at the last item.

### Example of the problem:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyBQ4.png)

### The solution should look like:

[ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr21t.png)

Here is a fragment of my jsp code:

```
    <s:if test="testDev == ''">
    <s:if test="reponseDTO.testDevItemDTOMap.size > 0">
        <div class="misc_pad" style="position:relative">
            <p class="p_spacer"><b>Dev</b></p>
            <s:iterator value="reponseDTO.testDevItemDTOMap" status="testDevStatus">
                <div class="menu_test">
                    <div>
                        <a href="expandtestDev_<s:property value="#testDevStatus.index" />" rel="expandtest">
                            <s:if test="reponseDTO.testDevNiveau2ItemDTOMap.get(key).size > 0"><img id="expandTree" src="<portal-logic:urlFindInTheme file="images/sdin/layout/open_content.gif" />" /> 
                            </s:if>
                        </a>
                        <a href="<s:property value="value.valeurP" />" rel="testDev" class="menu_test_lien">
                        <s:property value="value.libelle" /> (<s:property value="value.nombreDocuments" />)</a>
                    </div>
                    <s:if test="reponseDTO.testDevNiveau2ItemDTOMap.get(key).size > 0">
                        <ul id="expandtestDev_<s:property value="#testDevStatus.index" />"> 
                            <s:iterator value="reponseDTO.testDevNiveau2ItemDTOMap.get(key)" status="testDevNiveau2Status">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="menu_test">
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="expandtestDevNiveau2_<s:property value="#testDevStatus.index" />_<s:property value="#testDevNiveau2Status.index" />" rel="expandtest">
                                                <s:if test="reponseDTO.testDevNiveau3ItemDTOMap.get(valeurP).size > 0">
                                                    <img id="expandTree" src="<portal-logic:urlFindInTheme file="images/sdin/layout/open_content.gif" />" />
                                                </s:if>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="<s:property value="valeurP" />" rel="testDev" class="menu_test_lien">
                                                <s:property value="libelle" /> (<s:property value="nombreDocuments" />)
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <s:if test="reponseDTO.testDevNiveau3ItemDTOMap.get(valeurP).size > 0">
                                            <ul id="expandtestDevNiveau2_<s:property value="#testDevStatus.index" />_<s:property value="#testDevNiveau2Status.index" />">
                                                <s:iterator value="reponseDTO.testDevNiveau3ItemDTOMap.get(valeurP)" status="testDevNiveau3Status">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="<s:property value="valeurP" />" rel="testDev" class="menu_test_lien"><s:property value="libelle" /> (<s:property value="nombreDocuments" />)</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </s:iterator>                               
                                            </ul>
                                        </s:if>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </s:iterator>                               
                        </ul>
                    </s:if>
                </div>
            </s:iterator>
        </div>
    </s:if>                     
</s:if>
```

I found this piece of code that looks like what I want:

```css
 

   .test ul {
  padding:0;
  margin: 0; 
  margin-left:6px;
  list-style:none;
  background: #fff;
  color:#000;
  position:relative;
}

.test ul:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  border-left:1px solid #000;
}

.test li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 16px; 
  line-height:2em; 
  font-weight:bold;
  position:relative;
}

.test li:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:10px; 
  height:0;
  border-top:1px solid #000;
  margin-top:-1px; 
  position:absolute;
  top:1em; 
  left:0;
}

.test li:last-child:before {
  background:white; 
  height:auto;
  top:1em; 
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test">
        <div>
            <a href="#"> + </a>
            <a href="#"> Label A </a>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="test">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"> + </a>
                        <a href="#"> Label A1 </a>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        
                        <li>
                            <div class="test">
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#"> + </a>
                                    <a href="#"> Label A11 </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li>
                            <div class="test">
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#"> + </a>
                                    <a href="#"> Label A12 </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it using flex box refer the snippet below. Hope you are looking something like this

```css
.outerBdr{
  border-left:1px solid #dfdfdf;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content:space-between;
  overflow:auto
}
.cenBdr{
  position:relative;
  padding-left:30px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin-bottom:10px
}
.cenBdr label,.cenBdrInr label{
  position:relative;
  margin-right:5px;
  align-self:flex-start
} 
.cenBdr label:before, .cenBdrInr label:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -51px;
    width: 33px;
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    top: 50%;
}
.cenBdrInr label:before{
  width:30px;
  left:-48px
}
.cenBdrInr{
    align-items: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;  
    padding-left: 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    position:relative
}
.cenBdrInr > div{
  margin-bottom:10px;
  display:flex
}
.cenBdr input{
  align-self:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerBdr">
   <div class="cenBdr">
      <input type="checkbox" id="name">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
   </div>
   <div class="cenBdr">
      <input type="checkbox" id="mark">
      <label for="mark">Marks</label>
      <div class="cenBdrInr">
         <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="subj1">
            <label for="sub1">Subj1</label>
            <div class="cenBdrInr">
               <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="subj1">
                  <label for="sub1">Subj1</label>
               </div>
               <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="subj2">
                  <label for="subj2">subj2</label>
               </div>
               <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="subj3">
                  <label for="subj3">subj3</label>
                  <div class="cenBdrInr">
                     <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="subj1">
                        <label for="sub1">Subj1</label>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="subj2">
                        <label for="subj2">subj2</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="subj2">
            <label for="subj2">subj2</label>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="subj3">
            <label for="subj3">subj3</label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cenBdr">
      <input type="checkbox" id="id">
      <label for="id"> ID</label>
   </div>
   <div class="cenBdr">
      <input type="checkbox" id="rank">
      <label for="rank"> Rank</label>
   </div>
   <div class="cenBdr">
      <input type="checkbox" id="rating">
      <label for="rating"> rating</label>
       <div class="cenBdrInr">
         <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="subj1">
            <label for="sub1">Subj1</label>
            <div class="cenBdrInr">
               <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="subj1">
                  <label for="sub1">Subj1</label>
               </div>
               <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="subj2">
                  <label for="subj2">subj2</label>
               </div>
               <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="subj3">
                  <label for="subj3">subj3</label>
                  <div class="cenBdrInr">
                     <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="subj1">
                        <label for="sub1">Subj1</label>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="subj2">
                        <label for="subj2">subj2</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="subj2">
            <label for="subj2">subj2</label>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="subj3">
            <label for="subj3">subj3</label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cenBdr">
      <input type="checkbox" id="class">
      <label for="class"> class</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've made this, what I wanted was that the left bar stops at the last item no more